# Where is the AF-MF switch on a Tamron 70-300mm tele macro lens?

Tags: nikon, autofocus, tamron

[image][image][image]I am beginner. Recently bought a second hand Tamron 70-300mm tele-macro lens (model 572D) for nikon d5200. Its manual says it has AF-MF switch, but there is no switch I can see on it except normal/macro switch. I have attached the picture of lens model so please help to get autofocus working on it.

Comment: Sorry its just my pictures are duplicating and i am trying to removing it.

Comment: Only two images

Comment: You made it =) +1 for the effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote from the [572D manual](http://www.tamron-usa.com/assets/pdfs/572D.pdf):

> Automatic Focusing (for Nikon/Minolta/Pentax AF SLR)
>
> When the camera is on the autofocus mode, the lens focuses automatically.

Digging a little further, [this thread](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r23376240-Nikon-D3000-Tamron-AF-compatibility) confirms my suspicion that the Tamron lens doesn't have a built in focusing motor, but instead uses the screw drive motor which exists on higher-end Nikon bodies:

> Google helped me find a forum note that the D3000 needs a version of the lens with a built-in motor

As such, this lens won't autofocus on your camera as the D3x00 / D5x00 series don't have the screw drive motor.

Comment: So does it mean that i have to manually focus everytime when i take pics? and also why there is no switch on lens as in manual it shows it has af switch

Comment: Yes, and the AF/MF switch exists only for the Canon variant.